# How to create a python tcp server inside a docker container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, server, tcp

I have developed a python tcp server and assign the 5511 port number to it.
When I run it simply with "python3 server.py" its OK and server waits for connections.
But if I put it inside a container and run this command as docker command, I receive the "Cannot assign this port number" error"

My docker file

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /project

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5511

CMD ["python3", "server.py"]
```

I have try Exposing the port or port mapping but it does not work

Comment: What IP address does your server bind to? How do you run your container?

Comment: The IP address is in my current network and is not something important
And I run my container with docker run -dp 5511:5511 IMAGE_NAME or without port mapping

Comment: OK, I'll ask another way. Does your server bind to 127.0.0.1 or to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: What is the actual error message?  If you're manually setting up a socket listener, what does that code look like?

Comment: My IP is something like 192.168.1.221

Comment: Please add your code and exactly how you run it and try to access it else we are just guessing, thank you. Use [edit].

Comment: @AlirezaMortezaei: The server must bind to a valid IP address inside the container or to any (0.0.0.0). While the exact details of what you are doing are lacking your comments suggest, that you are trying to bind to an IP address outside of the container.

Comment: May be this port is already assigned to other program on host server?

try
docker run -dp 5512:5511 IMAGE_NAME

(it will map to 5512 port on host server)

Comment: please share your code and how you run it so it's possible to reproduce your issue